# How to parse JSON values using Swift 4?

Tags: ios, json, swift, search, tableview

GET `**Place**` values and those values from below JSON response and I need to store into array for tableview  `UISearchbar` search.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "class": "A",
    "Place": {
        "city": "sando",
        "state": "CA"
    }
 }, {
    "id": 1,
    "class": "B",
    "Place": {
        "city": "jambs",
        "state": "KA"
    }
 }]
```

I tried by using below code, Please help me to get particular values.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://*****.com/file.php")!
let request = URLRequest(url: url)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else {
        print("request failed \(error)")
            return
    }

    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String], let result = json["result"] {
            // Parse JSON
        }
    } catch let parseError {
        print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("raw response: \(responseString)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: There are countless examples and tutorials showing how to parse JSON data in Swift. Please do some basic research and attempt something. Then update your question with your relevant code and clearly explain what you have tried and what issues you are having. As a hint, search on JSONDecoder.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+get+JSON+values+using+Swift+4

Comment: OK, now you have posted code but you have not posted any information what help you need with the code. Please [edit] your question and include relevant details about what problems you are having with the code exactly.

Comment: I need to get id, class, city and state values and store into table array. @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cannot work. According to the given JSON the root object is an array `[[String: Any]]` and there is no key `result` at all.

```
let json = """
[{"id":1,"class":"A","Place":{"city":"sando","state":"CA"}},{"id":1,"class":"B","Place":{"city":"jambs","state":"KA"}}]
"""

let data = Data(json.utf8)

do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {
        for item in json {
            if let place = item["Place"] as? [String:String] {
                print(place["city"]!, place["state"]!)
            }
        }
    }
} catch let parseError {
    print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("raw response: \(responseString!)")
}
```

It's much more convenient to use the `Decodable` protocol to parse the JSON into structs

```
struct Response : Decodable {

    private enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case id, `class`, place = "Place" }

    let id : Int
    let `class` : String
    let place : Place
}

struct Place : Decodable {
    let city, state : String
}

...

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Response].self, from: data)
    for item in result {
        print(item.place.city, item.place.state)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Its not working @vadian. It is not printing nothing.

Comment: If the format of the received JSON matches exactly the JSON in the question it must work.

Comment: I tested the code with this JSON in a Playground. I does work. The error must be related to the code to load the data. Do you get an error?

Comment: I am not getting error. If you found results please edit your code. Thank you @vadian

Comment: I added the lines to be able to test the code stand-alone in a Playground

Comment: Wow great now its working. Thank you @Vadian btw one more doubt can I add those values into table data array because I want to list it out in tableview.

Comment: Use the struct version, declare the data source array as `[Response]` and assign `result` as the data source array. There are millions of examples and tutorials how to display the data in a table view.